# How to set qt applications to work nicely with different DPI screens in Windows 10?

Tags: qt, dpi, windows-10-desktop

For example, I have a high resolution (internal) screen and a low resolution external monitor. In Windows 10 when moving apps from one to the other screen they change automatically font size, iconsize, etc.

However, when trying this with qt creator apps they don't adjust so well. While the fon size is adjusted, the size of icons and buttons isn't. The image below shows the default qt "Application" example on the low res screen. The icons and the padding around menues is way too large.

[image]